# Convert string from a table to be used as a column for selection for another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table where I store records to be used as a column name for my queries where the record is an actual column on another table.

```
TBL_1 

COL_1
==========
SAMPLE_COL
```

```
TBL_2

SAMPLE_COL_1  SAMPLE_COL2
============  ===========
ABC           DEF
```

I'm having a problem using the record that I fetched to use as an actual column. I already tried a bunch of things like casting and using case (using case works but it's a bit of a brute force and I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this).

This is a sample query that I have tried:

```
SELECT (SELECT column_1 FROM tbl_1)
FROM tbl_2
```

Expected output

```
SAMPLE_COL_1
============
ABC
```

Actual output

```
(SELECT column_1 FROM tbl_1)
============================
SAMPLE_COL_1
```

This is what I've tried that worked so far but a brute force technique

```
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT column_1 FROM tbl_2) = 'SAMPLE_COL_1' THEN SAMPLE_COL_1
    ELSE SAMPLE_COL_2
  END
)
FROM tbl_2
```

Appreciate the help! Keep safe from COVID-19 everyone :)

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like you are dealing with an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) data model.  One of the worst ideas ever foisted on the relational database world.  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/.  If so, the best advice I can give is the same as given by the consultant in the article -- Run like

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is an unusual solution. We usually use the table where I stored the value in Java codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy as you'd want it to be - you'll have to use **dynamic SQL**. Here's an example, based on Scott's table(s).

Create a function that accepts table and column names and returns ref cursor.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_table_name in varchar2, par_column_name in varchar2)
  3  return sys_refcursor
  4  is
  5    rc sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    open rc for 'select ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(par_column_name) ||
  8                ' from '  || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name);
  9    return rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('dept', 'dname') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPT','DNAME
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME
--------------
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS


SQL> select f_test('dual', 'dummy') from dual;

F_TEST('DUAL','DUMMY
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

D
-
X


SQL>
```

---

Another example, with column (and table) names stored in a table (something like you posted).

Table that contains those info and the function:

```
SQL> select * from tbl_1;

TNAM CNAME
---- -----
dept dname
dual dummy

SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_table_name in varchar2)
  3  return sys_refcursor
  4  is
  5    l_str varchar2(1000);
  6    rc sys_refcursor;
  7  begin
  8    select 'select ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(cname) ||
  9           ' from '  || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(tname)
 10      into l_str
 11      from tbl_1
 12      where tname = dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name);
 13    open rc for l_str;
 14    return rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test('dept') from dual;

F_TEST('DEPT')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME
--------------
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS


SQL>
```

Comment: Performance-wise, is this better than using CASE/DECODE/COALESCE?

Comment: I don't know. My sample tables contain only dozen of rows so mostly *anything* I write will be *fast*. Test it and then you tell me. **However**, your approach (CASE) uses hardcoded columns anyway, so there's no purpose in using model you have (table and column names stored in a table which lead to **dynamic SQL**). If you use CASE, then forget about the whole model, entirely. The simplest and fastest option would be oldfashioned `select sample_col_1 from tbl_2`. No problem, no headache.